# Jquery get substring between parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

I have string like

> "Shabalu Sheedaa - Ali Gul Panara - Octa School - 10 (7)"

and I want to extract the value between parenthesis using jquery.
In this case it will be 7.

Comment: This has been asked 178434 times. `string.match(/\(\d+\)/)[0]`

Comment: And this is not a jquery problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var matches = regExp.exec("Shabalu Sheedaa - Ali Gul Panara - Octa School - 10 (7)");

//matches[1] contains the value between the parentheses
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Explation of Reg Exp:

```
Breakdown:

\( : match an opening parentheses
( : begin capturing group
[^)]+: match one or more non ) characters
) : end capturing group
\) : match closing parentheses
```

Comment: Explanation please