# Retrieve value from dynamic typed variable

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am calling documentdb select count in c# like this

```
var result = await this.documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<int>(documentCollectionUri, sql).AsDocumentQuery().ExecuteNextAsync();
var count = result.FirstOrDefault(); // {2}
```

The result from the query is the dynamic typed variable count which holds the value {2}

What is the best way to retrieve the value 2 from the variable?

Comment: result always will be in this format {any number}?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var indx1 = result.IndexOf("{");
var indx2 = result.IndexOf("}");
str = str.Substring(indx1+1, indx2-1);
```

You can also use regular expressions to achieve this

[Jquery get substring between parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030367/jquery-get-substring-between-parenthesis)

Please do not forget to mention your results.

Answer (score 0):

Calling count.ToString() actually gives me "2" and then I am parsing it to int.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you could specify the type of the object returned when invoking `IDocumentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync` without explicitly type conversion when you retrieving the result. You could modify your code as follows:

```html
var result = await this.documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<int>("{documentCollectionUri}","select value count(1) from c").AsDocumentQuery().ExecuteNextAsync<int>();
var count = result.FirstOrDefault(); // 2,int
```